# rosjava operating system

Tags: java, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

is rosjava for android only ?
Or can I use rosjava platform independant with any JavaVM ?

e.g. RaspberryPi / OSX / Linux / QNX

Background: I'd like to run nodes for IO-Sensors at small embeded systems.

Idee: something like ROSC with very small footprint and overhead

Thanks for any hints
Cheers
Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67666/rosjava-operating-system/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to use rosjava on any system with a Java VM.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1